# How to allow route parameter to use / or - in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For a sample link,

https://ddskart.com/product/COPIER%20TONER/NP-6/7/8000/71

How do I construct a `GET` route ?

the route must follow the given format.

```
Route::get('product/{category}/{model}/{product_id}', function ($category, $model, $product_id) {
    // do whatever ...
});
```

where the parameters could be

```
$category   = 'COPIER TONER';
$model   = 'NP-6/6/7/8000'; 
$product_id = 71;
```

Comment: Your `model` parameter uses slashes, you can try uri encoding your `model`, e.g. replace slash with `%2F`

Comment: where i add uri encoding in model and how please reply

Comment: you can use this function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, You can use regular expression constraints in you routes. Refer [Laravel Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).

```
Route::get('product/{category}/{model}/{product_id}', function ($category, $model, $product_id) {
    // do whatever ...
})->where([
    'category'   => '[\w\s]+',
    'model'      => '([a-zA-Z]+)\-(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)',
    'product_id' => '[\d]+'
]);
```

Please note that in above example provided regular expressions for **`category`**, **`model`**, and **`product_id`** parameters are to match the given url in the question. You can adjust them according to your logic. The point is you can take advantage of Laravel regular expression constrains while building complex routes.

Answer (score 0):

use  urlencode() and urldecode() php functions.

Comment: how to use that function in my laravel application